# AGP Upgrade Assistant in Android Studio Flamingo not progressing beyond loading screen

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 with the build Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023

When I try to run AGP Upgrade Assistant it shows me only loading and don't proceed further. There is also no expection thrown by the IDE itself.

[image]

I tried to change the jdk version to 17 but nothing happens.

Comment: where you able to solve the issue? I'm experiencing the same

Comment: @toom501 I updated my Android Studio to Giraffe and the issue is solved.

Comment: hmm I already have the latest version of Android Studio and I still have the same issue..